# Can't subtract string with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am playing around with Ruby, but I have some issues with subtracting something from a string using regex.

I have a string like this `http://mysite.com?test=100` where I would like to remove ?test=100. The regex to do this should be `\?(.*)` according to [rubular](http://rubular.com/).

I tried with `"http://mysite.com?test=100".sub \?(.*),''` but I keep getting the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end "http://mysite.com?test=100".sub \?(.*),''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to embrace your regexp in `//`:

```
1.9.3-p286 :013 > "http://mysite.com?test=100".sub /\?(.*)/, ''
 => "http://mysite.com"
```

But anyway I suggest you to use something like this for such case:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse("http://mysite.com?test=100")
uri.host # => mysite.com
uri.scheme # => http
```

Comment: I need more stuff than just the host and scheme, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

You should really use a library to do this, such as [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) from Ruby’s Standard Library:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse 'http://mysite.com?test=100'
uri.query = nil
uri.to_s  #=> "http://mysite.com"
```